Movie with magical jewel / stone which turns you invisible when put inside your mouth?
A long time ago, when i was a kid/teen, I watched a movie about knights, and battles among them.
I really don't remember anything about the story (other than it was fiction, rather than Historical), but what i remember very well, is that some character looks for a magic Jewel (or Stone) which when you put it in the mouth turns you invisible.
I also kind of remember that the stone/jewel is found on a statue's mouth. And the character who finds it gets an obvious advantage against their enemies.
I estimate is a movie from late 80's , early 90's
Any ideas?

I also vaguely remember something like that from some sword-and-sorcery movie, but there were so many of them in the 80s...

Random guess, but might it be The Emerald Forest (1985), where a child looks for magic stones that turn the members of a tribe invisible ?

The original movie name is:  I paladini - Storia d'armi e d'amori (Hearts and armour in English).
On YouTube you have the all movie, enjoy:




it may be it! I dot have time at this very moment to watch it full, so could you help me telling in what minute does the scene of the stone/jewel happens? just to be sure is the one i rememer. Thanks!

update, i skipped along the movie and found the scene! it's at 59:00. i really didn't remember much of the movie whatsoever, but definitely matches the few things I remembered (magical jewel and knights in armour). Thank you!

@DiegoDD If this was the right answer, please accept it so we'd know it's resolved.

yeah sorry, i totally forgot to accept, it is definitely the right one!
